# Defining Templates and Manipulating using Java

Tags: java, pdf, reporting

As part of my project requirement I am looking at creating predefined templates which have the fonts and indentation pre-defined with fixed variable parts which I want to replace at runtime and generate PDF. These could be replacing a single variable example #Name or inserting a repeating group #List of Orders.

I was looking at creating PDF's with tags and then reading via PDFBox and replacing them. However it seems that without knowing the predefined position there is no way to replace text using PDFBox.

Is there any alternatives I need to look at? I need to be able to have seperate Headers on each Page and be able to replace tags with the variables.

Thanks
Arnab

Comment: PDF isn't a Word processing format, so when you say "I have existing PDF documents in which I want to replace one word with another," a PDF expert hears: "I have onion soup, and I want to replace the onions with tomatoes." I assume that you're not making a joke, so I'll try not to laugh with your question, but have you looked at PDF forms? Is using PDF AcroForm technology an option for you?

Comment: Do you have the source of those PDFs? Maybe those have a *readable* format. You need to know that when converting to PDF you loose word information and also many other information about your content structure. PDF just contains stuff like *place some strokes at this coordinates and another stroke at that coordinate*. That's also why manipulating PDFs is hard and why the good editors cost much.

Answer (score 0):

Creating templates for your fonts and layout is a great idea.  Instead of using PDF documents as templates you can use word processor documents (doc/docx/odt), populate them and then convert to PDF.

If that approach suits your purpose, you can use the Libre Office Java API to manipulate templates and save as PDF.  This means you can create a DOC or ODT file as your template (with the varying headers) and place-holders for the data and your Java program can control Libre Office to load the document, update the placeholders and save as PDF.  The following Java code replaces 3 placeholders in the template and saves a pdf:

```
// Initialise
XComponentContext xContext = Bootstrap.bootstrap();

XMultiComponentFactory xMCF = xContext.getServiceManager();

Object oDesktop = xMCF.createInstanceWithContext(
     "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", xContext);

XDesktop xDesktop = (XDesktop) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
     XDesktop.class, oDesktop);

// Load the Document
String workingDir = "C:/projects/";
String myTemplate = workingDir + "letterTemplate.doc";

if (!new File(myTemplate).canRead()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot load template:" + new File(myTemplate));
}

XComponentLoader xCompLoader = (XComponentLoader) UnoRuntime
    .queryInterface(com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader.class, xDesktop);

String sUrl = "file:///" + myTemplate;

PropertyValue[] propertyValues = new PropertyValue[0];

propertyValues = new PropertyValue[1];
propertyValues[0] = new PropertyValue();
propertyValues[0].Name = "Hidden";
propertyValues[0].Value = new Boolean(true);

XComponent xComp = xCompLoader.loadComponentFromURL(
    sUrl, "_blank", 0, propertyValues);

// Manipulate
XReplaceDescriptor xReplaceDescr = null;
XReplaceable xReplaceable = null;

XTextDocument xTextDocument = (XTextDocument) UnoRuntime
        .queryInterface(XTextDocument.class, xComp);

xReplaceable = (XReplaceable) UnoRuntime
        .queryInterface(XReplaceable.class,
                xTextDocument);

xReplaceDescr = (XReplaceDescriptor) xReplaceable
        .createReplaceDescriptor();

// mail merge the date
xReplaceDescr.setSearchString("<date>");
xReplaceDescr.setReplaceString(new Date().toString());
xReplaceable.replaceAll(xReplaceDescr);

// mail merge the addressee
xReplaceDescr.setSearchString("<addressee>");
xReplaceDescr.setReplaceString("Best Friend");
xReplaceable.replaceAll(xReplaceDescr);

// mail merge the signatory
xReplaceDescr.setSearchString("<signatory>");
xReplaceDescr.setReplaceString("John Steady");
xReplaceable.replaceAll(xReplaceDescr);

// save as a PDF
XStorable xStorable = (XStorable) UnoRuntime
        .queryInterface(XStorable.class, xComp);

propertyValues = new PropertyValue[2];
// Setting the flag for overwriting
propertyValues[0] = new PropertyValue();
propertyValues[0].Name = "Overwrite";
propertyValues[0].Value = new Boolean(true);
// Setting the filter name
propertyValues[1] = new PropertyValue();
propertyValues[1].Name = "FilterName";
propertyValues[1].Value = "writer_pdf_Export";

// Appending the favoured extension to the origin document name
String myResult = workingDir + "letter1.pdf";
xStorable.storeToURL("file:///" + myResult, propertyValues);

System.out.println("Saved " + myResult);

// shutdown
xDesktop.terminate();
```

You can find an explanation of the code in this blog [java-convert-word-to-pdf-part-1](https://www.docmosis.com/company/blog/item/java-convert-word-to-pdf-part-1.html).  Please note I work for Docmosis.

I hope that helps.